# Why does scanf reacts like this?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, stdio

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *dumb = (char*)malloc(50);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", dumb);
    printf("%s\n",dumb);

    scanf("%[^\n]s", dumb);
    printf("%s\n", dumb);

    return 0;
}
```

I need help with the code, if I run this code and write in the first scanf "Hellow World" it prints out 2 "Hello Worlds" and jumps over the other scanf ,
 and well how do I fix it??

[image]

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", dumb);` --> `scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", dumb);`

Comment: Why the C++ tag? This is pure C (except of the proprietary MS stuff).

Comment: @Ciomegu You tagged this as `C++`, and I can bet that even Stroustrup himself couldn't figure out the scanf gobbledygook : `"%[^\n]s"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all dont use C style cast, use static cast instead:

```
auto dumb = static_cast<char*>(malloc(50));
```

and you need `cin.ignore()` after first `printf` to clear up the buffer:

```
auto dumb = static_cast<char*>(malloc(50));
scanf("%[^\n]s", dumb);
printf("%s\n", dumb);
std::cin.ignore();
scanf("%[^\n]s", dumb);
printf("%s\n", dumb);
```

or you can use solution mentioned in the comment section:

```
scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", dumb);
```

Comment: Weird mix of C and C++

Comment: It's like breaking compatibility with C by sprinkling dangerous code with superficial C++ improvements, ending up with code that is the worst of both worlds: no C++ type safety, no C compatibility.

Comment: Will working with `std::cin` take effect on `FILE *`?

Answer (score 0):

Empty your input buffer after `scanf`.

```
char *dumb = (char*)malloc(50);
scanf("%[^\n]s", dumb);
fflush(stdin);  //flush remaining input buffer
printf("%s\n",dumb); 


scanf("%[^\n]s", dumb); 
fflush(stdin);
printf("%s\n", dumb);
```